# How to display magento product categories in column wise

Tags: php, magento, foreach, html-lists, product

I'm trying to display all the categories below the main title, so I want to display four categories in each column. The below is my code

```
<?php
    $_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($_category->entity_id);
    $helper     = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
?>
<ul class="pull-left">
<?php foreach ($collection as $cat):?>
    <li>
       <a style="color:#fff;" href="<?php echo $helper->getCategoryUrl($cat);?>">
          <cite><?php echo $cat->getName();?><?php
 ?></cite>
        </a>
    </li>
<?php endforeach;?>
</ul>
```

HTML Output

```
<ul class="pull-left">
    <li>....</li>
    <li>....</li>
    <li>....</li>
    <li>....</li>
    <li>....</li>
    <li>....</li>
    <li>....</li>
    <li>....</li>
    .
    .
    .
    .
</ul>
```

I want to define four `li` items in every `ul`. Like this

```
<ul class="pull-left">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
<ul class="pull-left">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

I also want to display product count and I've tried this

```
<?php 
    $products_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)->getProductCount();
?>
```

but it is not working.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "*it is not working*"?

Comment: It's just not displaying product counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this code on my category page and it is giving me count.
Please have a look at the code I have added before  tag.

```
<?php 

$loadCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
//echo 'loadCategory = '.$_categoryID = $loadCategory->getId();

$subCategories = explode(',', $loadCategory->getChildren());
?>

<ul class="pull-left">


<?php $i=1;
    foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId )
    {
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);

        if($cat->getIsActive())
        {
            if($cat->getImageUrl())
            {
                //echo '<a href="'.$cat->getURL().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a></br>';
                echo '<li>';

                echo '<a style="color:#fff;" href="'.$cat->getUrl().'">'.$this->escapeHtml($cat->getName()); echo"<br>";
                echo $total = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->setCurrentCategory($subCategoryId)->getProductCollection()->getSize();
                echo'</a>';
                echo '</li>';

            if($i%4==0)
            {
                echo'</ul><ul class="pull-left">';
            }

            }

        }
        $i++;
    }  

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this one.

You can adjust ul ,li as per wish. Right now this will list four subcategories in a single row.

This code will give you the subcategories of a parent category.

```
<?php 

$loadCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
//echo 'loadCategory = '.$_categoryID = $loadCategory->getId();

$subCategories = explode(',', $loadCategory->getChildren());
?>

<ul class="pull-left">


<?php $i=1;
    foreach ( $subCategories as $subCategoryId )
    {
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCategoryId);

        if($cat->getIsActive())
        {
            if($cat->getImageUrl())
            {
            //echo '<a href="'.$cat->getURL().'">'.$cat->getName().'</a></br>';
            echo '<li>';




                echo '<a style="color:#fff;" href="'.$cat->getUrl().'">'.$this->escapeHtml($cat->getName()).'</a>';

            echo '</li>';

            if($i%4==0)
            {
                echo'</ul><ul class="pull-left">';
            }

            }

        }
        $i++;
    }  

?>

</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks your code perfectly worked after I tweaked it. Can you help to get product count as well?

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code. This will surely work for you.

```
<?php
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryID);

echo $total = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->setCurrentCategory($category)->getProductCollection()->getSize();

?>
```

Thanks,

Comment: This code is not working. Can you accept my edit version of the main answer above? Thereafter try to tweak the code before </a> so that the counts display under the link of the category/sub-category.

Comment: Can you post you code here that you have done using the reference code I have posted? This will help in figuring out the issue.